Decomposition of an $\text{SL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ representation
Let $W = V \oplus V^*$, where $V$ is the standard $\text{SL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ rep and $V^*$ is its dual. I'm ultimately trying to decompose the space $(W \otimes \bigwedge^2 W) / {\bigwedge^3 W}$.
This copy of $\bigwedge^3 W$ lies inside $\bigwedge^2 W \otimes W$ via the map $a \wedge b \wedge c \mapsto a \otimes (b \wedge c) - b \otimes (a \wedge c) + c \otimes (a \wedge b)$.
$$\bigwedge\nolimits^3 W = \bigwedge\nolimits^3 V \oplus (\bigwedge\nolimits^2 V \otimes V^*) \oplus (V \oplus \bigwedge\nolimits^2 V^*) \oplus \bigwedge\nolimits^3 V^*.$$
What's confusing me is that $W \otimes \wedge^2 W$ contains two copies each of $\bigwedge^2 V \otimes V^*$ and $V \oplus \bigwedge^2 V^*$, and I don't see which ones survive after quotienting out by $\bigwedge^3 W$. What does a vector belonging to each copy (the one killed and the one nontrivial in the quotient) look like? Or am I missing something entirely?

I wonder if one ought to use \wedge in things like $a \otimes (b \wedge c) - b \otimes (a \wedge c) + c \otimes (a \wedge b)$ and \bigwedge in things like $\bigwedge^3W$.

Your space seems to be the Schur module $E^{\lambda}\left(W\right)$ for the partition $\lambda = \left(2,1\right)$, as defined in §8.1 of William Fulton's Young tableaux. At least I am sure that the quotient of $E^{\times\lambda}$ by Fulton's conditions (1) and (2) is $\wedge^2 W \otimes W$; but I also suspect (and I know it can't be hard to check) that the remaining condition (3) factors out the $\wedge^3 W$.
Now this gives its character as a $\operatorname{GL}\left(W\right)$-module. Remains to break it down in terms of $V$.

Note that if you have multiplicity greater than $1$ of a subrepresentation, then there are many ways to decompose that isotypic component into copies of the subrepresentation. Consider $V \oplus V$ for some representation $V$. We could also decompose this as $U \oplus W$ where $U = \{(v,v)|v\in V\}$ and $W = \{(v,-v)|v\in V\}$ both of which are clearly subrepresentations isomorphic to $V$ (you might call these the diagonal and antidiagonal subrepresentations compared to our original decomposition).
So the copy of $ \bigwedge^2 V \otimes V^* $ that gets sent to $0$ in the quotient is simply the bit of the image of $\bigwedge^3 W$ that forms a copy of $ \bigwedge^2 V \otimes V^* $ and the copy that doesn't is whatever complementary copy of it that you want to pick. If you have already defined the decomposition of $\bigwedge^2 W \otimes W$ you may find, for example, that both of your chosen copies survive quotienting but are in fact being identified with each other.
